# How to check if PDImage is rotated within the PDF with PdfBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, affinetransform

I need to draw PDF page on my own screen (text paragraphs and images) without using Graphics. I have loaded PDImage object and have an AffineTransform instance, but not sure how to determine if image is rotated and if so, what is the angle. 
Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561909/finding-angle-from-transform-matrix

Comment: If the image not only is rotated but also skewed, it is not clear which angle you mean. Do you mean the angle by which the x axis is rotated? Or the y axis? Or some arbitrary other such line?