# extract rotation, scale values from 2d transformation matrix (more clarification)

Tags: math, matrix, transformation

I have read the questions related to my query [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13150/115956) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4361242/713573). Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361442/713573) I have calculated the scale, rotation and translation. Some mistake certainly I have done that's why I could not get the correct values.
Here are my detailed steps:

- **Step 1:** Here is my initial div in brown color with four different colors corners for which I'll apply transformation whereas origin is 0,0

```html
<body>
  <div id="viewport" style="left:100px;top:50px;position:relative;">
    <div id="maptiles" style="
  position:absolute; left:0px;top:0px;
  width:500px; height: 500px; border:2px solid #BF9212;
  transform-origin:0px 0px;
  ">
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px; width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #BF9212;"></div>
      <div style="position: absolute; left:0px; top: 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid red;"></div>
      <div style="position: absolute; left:400px; top: 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid green;"></div>
      <div style="position: absolute; left:0px; top: 400px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid pink;"></div>
      <div style="position: absolute; left:400px; top: 400px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid blue;"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- just cartision lines as base-->
    <svg width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <rect x="0" y="0" height="500" width="500" style="stroke:gray; fill: none;stroke-width:5px">
      </rect>
      <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="500" y2="100" style="stroke:gray" />
      <line x1="0" y1="200" x2="500" y2="200" style="stroke:gray" />
      <line x1="0" y1="300" x2="500" y2="300" style="stroke:gray" />
      <line x1="0" y1="400" x2="500" y2="400" style="stroke:gray" />
      <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="500" style="stroke:gray" />
      <line x1="200" y1="0" x2="200" y2="500" style="stroke:gray" />
      <line x1="300" y1="0" x2="300" y2="500" style="stroke:gray" />
      <line x1="400" y1="0" x2="400" y2="500" style="stroke:gray" />
    </svg>
</body>
```

- **Step 2:** Next I apply different transformations:

  ```
  transform:translate(250px, 250px) rotate(45deg) translate(-250px, -250px) translate(38px, 250px) rotate(20deg) translate(-38px, -250px) scale(.5)
  ```

```html
<body>
<div id="viewport" style="left:100px;top:50px;position:relative;">
<div id="maptiles"
  style="position:absolute; left:0px;top:0px;
  width:500px; height: 500px; border:2px solid #BF9212;
  transform-origin:0px 0px;
  transform:translate(250px, 250px) rotate(45deg) translate(-250px, -250px) translate(38px, 250px) rotate(20deg) translate(-38px, -250px) scale(.5);  
  ">
     <div style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px; width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #BF9212;"></div>
     <div style="position: absolute; left:0px; top: 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid red;"></div>
     <div style="position: absolute; left:400px; top: 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid green;"></div>
     <div style="position: absolute; left:0px; top: 400px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid pink;"></div>
     <div style="position: absolute; left:400px; top: 400px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid blue;"></div>
 
 </div>
  <!-- just cartision lines as base-->
<svg width="500" height="500"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="500" width="500" style="stroke:gray; fill: none;stroke-width:5px" >
  </rect>
  <line x1="0"  y1="100" x2="500"   y2="100" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="0"  y1="200" x2="500"   y2="200" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="0"  y1="300" x2="500"   y2="300" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="0"  y1="400" x2="500"   y2="400" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="100"  y1="0" x2="100"   y2="500" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="200"  y1="0" x2="200"   y2="500" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="300"  y1="0" x2="300"   y2="500" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="400"  y1="0" x2="400"   y2="500" style="stroke:gray"/>
</svg>
</body>
```

- **Step 3:** Now I calculate the matrix transformation for all above transformations and apply to the original div:

  ```
  transform: matrix(0.21130913087034978,0.45315389351832497,-0.45315389351832497,0.21130913087034978,310.61081520146786,-40.000898954115684)
  ```

```html
<body>
<div id="viewport" style="left:100px;top:50px;position:relative;">
<div id="maptiles"
  style="position:absolute; left:0px;top:0px;
  width:500px; height: 500px; border:2px solid #BF9212;
  transform-origin:0px 0px;
  transform: matrix(0.21130913087034978,0.45315389351832497,-0.45315389351832497,0.21130913087034978,310.61081520146786,-40.000898954115684);
  ">
     <div style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px; width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #BF9212;"></div>
     <div style="position: absolute; left:0px; top: 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid red;"></div>
     <div style="position: absolute; left:400px; top: 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid green;"></div>
     <div style="position: absolute; left:0px; top: 400px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid pink;"></div>
     <div style="position: absolute; left:400px; top: 400px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid blue;"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- just cartision lines as base-->
<svg width="500" height="500"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="500" width="500" style="stroke:gray; fill: none;stroke-width:5px" >
  </rect>
  <line x1="0"  y1="100" x2="500"   y2="100" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="0"  y1="200" x2="500"   y2="200" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="0"  y1="300" x2="500"   y2="300" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="0"  y1="400" x2="500"   y2="400" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="100"  y1="0" x2="100"   y2="500" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="200"  y1="0" x2="200"   y2="500" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="300"  y1="0" x2="300"   y2="500" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="400"  y1="0" x2="400"   y2="500" style="stroke:gray"/>
</svg>
</body>
```

and I get the same out put as in "step 2"

I am using [transformatrix](https://github.com/chrisaljoudi/transformatrix.js) module to calculate the transformation matrix.

- **step 4:** Finally I calculate the scale, rotation and translation based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361442/713573) .

  ```
  transform: rotate(-25deg) scale(0.5) translate(310.611px,-40px)
  ```

```html
<body>
<div id="viewport" style="left:100px;top:50px;position:relative;">
<div id="maptiles"
  style="position:absolute; left:0px;top:0px;
  width:500px; height: 500px; border:2px solid #BF9212;
  transform-origin:0px 0px;
  transform: rotate(-25deg) scale(0.5) translate(310.611px,-40px);
  ">
     <div style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px; width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #BF9212;"></div>
     <div style="position: absolute; left:0px; top: 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid red;"></div>
     <div style="position: absolute; left:400px; top: 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid green;"></div>
     <div style="position: absolute; left:0px; top: 400px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid pink;"></div>
     <div style="position: absolute; left:400px; top: 400px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid blue;"></div>
  
  </div>
  <!-- just cartision lines as base-->
<svg width="500" height="500"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="500" width="500" style="stroke:gray; fill: none;stroke-width:5px" >
  </rect>
  <line x1="0"  y1="100" x2="500"   y2="100" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="0"  y1="200" x2="500"   y2="200" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="0"  y1="300" x2="500"   y2="300" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="0"  y1="400" x2="500"   y2="400" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="100"  y1="0" x2="100"   y2="500" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="200"  y1="0" x2="200"   y2="500" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="300"  y1="0" x2="300"   y2="500" style="stroke:gray"/>
  <line x1="400"  y1="0" x2="400"   y2="500" style="stroke:gray"/>
</svg>
</body>
```

And apply these transformations to the original div and it does not look alike the output of "step 2 or "step 3". I was expecting it would give me the combined transformations in scale, rotation and translation.

**My requirement:** Many transformations would be applied on the div by user and at the end I would allow to store the combined/final rotation, scale and translation to user.

Please let me know where am I doing wrong or is this not possible (to calculate the combined values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying a [transform matrix in HTML](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/), the following code:

```
transform: matrix(a, b, c, d, tx, ty);
```

corresponds to the following matrix:

```
| a c tx |    
| b d ty |
| 0 0 1  |
```

Notice that c and b are swapped compared to the answers you linked.

Alternatively you could swap b and c in the matrix and think of the HTML code as:

```
transform: matrix(a, c, b, d, tx, ty);
```

So for this matrix:

```
transform: matrix(0.21130913087034978,0.45315389351832497,-0.45315389351832497,0.21130913087034978,310.61081520146786,-40.000898954115684)
```

the rotation angle is atan(0.45315389351832497/0.21130913087034978) = 65 degrees.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. And the correct formula for rotation is `atan2(b,a)` not `atan2(-b,a)` ?

Comment: For the example matrix above, it's atan(-c,a) because b and c are swapped due to a different convention for mapping the list of values to the position in the matrix. And since b = -c, atan2(b,a) will give the correct result.

Comment: One more observation the order mentioned of final transformations in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4361442/713573) `rotation, followed by scale and then translation` seems wrong I am getting the correct view if order is `translation rotation scale` or in English he means same.